# OR Operator Short-circuit in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, short-circuiting

I want to consult SQL Server OR short-circuit

Code:

```
DECLARE @tempTable table
    (
        id int
    )
INSERT @tempTable(id) values(1)
      
DECLARE @id varchar(10)
SET @id = 'x'
SELECT * FROM @tempTable WHERE 1=1 OR id = @id --successfully
SELECT * FROM @tempTable WHERE @id = 'x' OR id = @id --Exception not Convert 'x' to int
```

Why? `1=1` and `@id='x'` are `true`.

SQL Server OR operator : whether the short-circuit function？

THANKS

Comment: There is **no guarantee** whatsoever on how and which parts of an `OR` condition are evaluated first (or at all). T-SQL is **NOT** like C# in that way. You **cannot** rely on boolean short-circuiting.

Comment: `Why? 1=1 and @id='x' is true` - it is **or** actually, not **and**.

Comment: Here, in this INSERT @tempTable(id) values(1),INTO is missing.

Comment: OR short circuited is My doubts    but my office codeing sql is((@id is NULL OR id = id) AND (@name IS NULL OR name=@name)) so I would like to know whether the short-circuit Because This decision process efficiency To do so, just reuse the query plan

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Within SQL, there **is no requirement** that an OR clause breaks early.  In other words, it is up to the optimizer whether to check both conditions simutaneously.  I am not an expert in the MSSQL optimizer, but I have seen instances where the optimizer has and has not short circuited an OR clause.

Comment: OR short circuited is My doubts    but my office codeing sql is((@id is NULL OR id = id) AND (@name IS NULL OR name=@name)) so I would like to know whether the short-circuit Because This decision process efficiency To do so, just reuse the query plan

Comment: I have just experienced a confusing case that demonstrates this. I was trying to parse JSON out of a varchar field, and I included a WHERE clause to include only the rows with valid JSON text. So far so good; running the SELECT works. Using that query in a WITH and joining it to another table works. But *any* attempt to write a WHERE condition dependent upon that column, even several queries later joining on the WITH table, results in JSON parsing failures. The optimizer is magical indeed.

Answer (score 7):

Just stumbled over this question, and had already found this blog-entry: http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/

The SQL server is free to optimize a query anywhere it sees fit, so in the example given in the blog post, you cannot rely on short-circuiting.

However, a CASE is apparently documented to evaluate in the written order - check the comments of that blog post.

Answer (score -4):

It is but obvious that MS Sql server supports Short circuit theory, to improve the performance by avoiding unnecessary checking,

Supporting Example:

```
SELECT 'TEST'
WHERE 1 = 'A'

SELECT 'TEST'
WHERE 1 = 1 OR 1 = 'A'
```

Here, the first example would result into error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.'

While the second runs easily as the condition 1 = 1 evaluated to TRUE and thus the second condition doesn't ran at all.

Further more

```
SELECT 'TEST'
WHERE 1 = 0 OR 1 = 'A'
```

here the first condition would evaluate to false and hence the DBMS would go for the second condition and again you will get the error of conversion as in above example.

NOTE: I WROTE THE ERRONEOUS CONDITION JUST TO REALIZE WEATHER THE CONDITION IS EXECUTED OR SHORT-CIRCUITED
IF QUERY RESULTS IN ERROR MEANS THE CONDITION EXECUTED, SHORT-CIRCUITED OTHERWISE.

SIMPLE EXPLANATION

Consider,

```
WHERE 1 = 1 OR 2 = 2
```

as the first condition is getting evaluated to **TRUE**, its meaningless to evaluate the second condition because its evaluation in whatever value
would not affect the result at all, so its good opportunity for Sql Server to save Query Execution time by skipping unnecessary condition checking or evaluation.

in case of **"OR"** if first condition is evaluated to **TRUE** the entire chain connected by **"OR"** would considered as evaluated to true without evaluating others.

```
condition1 OR condition2 OR ..... OR conditionN
```

if the condition1 is evaluated to true, rest all of the conditions till conditionN would be skipped.
In generalized words at determination of first **TRUE**, all other conditions linked by OR would be skipped.

Consider the second condition

```
WHERE 1 = 0 AND 1 = 1
```

as the first condition is getting evalutated to **FALSE** its meaningless to evaluate the second condition because its evaluation in whatever value
would not affect the result at all, so again its good opportunity for Sql Server to save Query Execution time by skipping unnecessary condition checking or evaluation.

in case of **"AND"** if first condition is evaluated to **FALSE** the entire chain connected with the **"AND"** would considered as evaluated to FALSE without evaluating others.

```
condition1 AND condition2 AND ..... conditionN
```

if the condition1 is evaluated to **FALSE**, rest all of the conditions till **conditionN** would be skipped.
In generalized words at determination of first **FALSE**, all other conditions linked by **AND** would be skipped.

THEREFOR, A WISE PROGRAMMER SHOULD ALWAYS PROGRAM THE CHAIN OF CONDITIONS IN SUCH A WAY THAT, LESS EXPENSIVE OR MOST ELIMINATING CONDITION GETS EVALUATED FIRST,
OR ARRANGE THE CONDITION IN SUCH A WAY THAT CAN TAKE MAXIMUM BENEFIT OF SHORT CIRCUIT

**Thanks and Regards,**

**Rk_Hirpara**

Comment: Downvote reason: always test things on a real server, with a reasonable data set. For example, try this more realistic where clause against a character field - where isnumeric(fieldname) = 1 AND convert(decimal, fieldname) <= 0  - you will find that it suffers a conversion error on rows where isnumeric = 0, even though it technically should not need to evaluate the second condition on such rows.

Comment: I hardly ever downvote, but this answer is apparently just wrong.