# Sql Server Comparison behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I find this hard to test/research so im asking: In a `OR` similar to `where (1 = 1) OR (column1 = @value)` condition, will the second part, eg: `column1 = @value` ever be tested? If possible please provide documentation...

Comment: It's called short-circuiting, which SQL Server does *not* do.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219791/or-operator-short-circuit-in-sql-server and http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/02/22/sql-server-short-circuit.aspx

Comment: Check [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/logical-operators-or-and-in-condition-and-order-of-conditions-in-where) also

Answer (score 0):

According to this post by Mladen Prajdić, the answer is no, SQL Server does not do short-circuiting for OR conditions:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/02/25/How-SQL-Server-short-circuits-WHERE-condition-evaluation.aspx

Also, see [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219791/or-operator-short-circuit-in-sql-server)

If order really matters to you, you can use a `CASE WHEN` statement.  SQL Server always evaluates `CASE WHEN` conditions in order.